# What is the function for "unwrapping" a cylinder onto a plane? And why does it preserve geodesic distance?

Tags: geometry

If a cylinder is described by $ \{ (x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}:x^2+y^2=r^2 \} $ where $r$ is constant, and the set is "unwrapped" to the rectangle with width $2\pi r$ and, say, with $y=0$, $z$ preserved, what is the function that would correctly map the $x$ coordinate?

For illustration, allow me to borrow from [this article](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/apostol388.pdf). See Figure 4(a). Without the cutting cylinder.

Unwrapping in real life probably means preserving distance between points with the same $x,y$ coordinates on the cylinder and points with the same $z$ coordinate.

But it seems, in effect, distances between any points are preserved under this map. So I am curious why that is.

Or is there a simpler way to see the distance preserving effect?

I got my question upon seeing [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4567289/133152), where the solution assumes geodesics on cylinder is preserved under "unwrapping". [That much is true](https://www.gregschool.org/articles-page-6/2017/5/18/finding-the-geodesic-on-a-cylinder-mley2), but the reasoning I can think of is not really basic geometry.

Comment: It may be easier to think of unwrapping a circle onto a line. Either way, it helps to write the two surfaces' Cartesian coordinates as functions of the cylinder's polar coordinate.

Comment: @J.G.: I was more wondering if there is some well known result that I am not aware of. If I was to solve the problem, I'd think of a point's position on the circle as a parameter in relation to the circumference. So distance to a chosen center point on the circle -> $x$ coordinate. And then translate to $y=0$. That is what unwrapping in 2D should be: preserving distance. Maybe a bit clumsy. But with that, I understand your hint. Still I am having trouble seeing why it preserves distance in the cylinder to plane case

Comment: There is no "local isometry" from the cylinder to the plane, but there _is_ a local isometry from the plane to the cylinder, for example, sending $(u, v)$ to $$(x, y, z) = (r\cos(u/r), r\sin(u/r), v).$$The differential-geometric way to show this mapping preserves geodesics is to calculate the "induced metric" or "first fundamental form," which turns out to be $du^2+dv^2$. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: Yes indeed. I wouldn't know why the induced metric means it preserves geodesics though. Would you be able to explain or is that too big a topic?  Separately, when I think of geodesic, I can only think of calculus of variation. Hence the [linked webpage] in the question. Though I don't particularly like the assumption+manipulation of arclength formula there, assuming the validity in parametrization via azimuth. Whatever formula it is, would like to know why it is the arc length as in least upper bound of all possible discrete Riemann sums along the path.

Comment: The first issue (the form of the metric characterizes geodesics) is sort of lengthy, but amounts to Gauss's equations for a surface and the intrinsic nature of geodesics, and can be found in a differential geometry text. <> The second, why arc length is the sup of Riemann sums, is the usual definition; why it's a _good_ definition might be a bit lengthy. :) (One subtlety is that a "sup of inscribed areas" idea does _not_ work for smooth surfaces! Spivak Volume II(?) has a good explanation if memory serves.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: Thank you for the explanations. What is the Gauss' equations? Sup of Riemann sums is what I think of as physically relatable. (not a mathematician.) The [linked page](https://www.gregschool.org/articles-page-6/2017/5/18/finding-the-geodesic-on-a-cylinder-mley2) applies Euler-Lagrange equation to find geodesic would be inline with what I think of as intuitive. But why should paths on cylinders be smoothly parametrizable through the various angle coordinates? (The article was written by a physicist/engineer. Tbh, probably doesnt know assumptions required for arc length formulas.)

Comment: Gauss's equations (in the sense here) give the Christoffel symbols (or equivalently, the covariant derivative, or parallel transport) of a surface in terms of the metric components and their derivatives. Good search terms include _Gauss-Codazzi equations_, and _Theorema Egregium_ (Gauss's "great theorem" that the Gaussian curvature depends only on the metric, not the second fundamental form, i.e., is intrinsic). @TedShifrin has [AMS Open Math Notes](https://www.ams.org/open-math-notes/omn-view-listing?listingId=110755) containing a detailed account, but again it's not a short story....

Comment: Searching Math.SE for "geodesics local isometry" or similar phrases may also turn up useful answers, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365053/local-isometries-preserve-geodesics Qualitatively, if we believe geodesics are locally length minimizing, then the concept of _geodesic_ should depend only on intrinsic geometry, not how the surface bends when embedded in Euclidean three-space. Since a local isometry (such as wrapping the plane around a cylinder) preserves the metric locally, plane geodesics map to cylindrical geodesics. [...]

Comment: Further, for every point $p$ of the cylinder and every tangent vector $v$ at $p$, there is an image of a Euclidean plane geodesic through $p$ with initial velocity $v$, which is therefore a geodesic of the cylinder through $p$ with initial velocity $v$, and therefore (by uniqueness) _the_ geodesic through $p$ with initial velocity $v$. (If that's essentially what you're asking, I or someone else can type up an answer....)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: Thank you again for the links and patient explanations. Rough conceptual outlines like the you gave is what I am asking. Though I'll be honest: I don't understand it. Would you be able to explain why wrapping is a local isometry? I was a bit confused when you said there isn't a local isometry from cylinder to plan as well. Separately, I can believe local isometry preserves geodesics. I understand the story for that is not short. Any rough outline would be kind efforts and nice answer.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang:  But what you said, local isometry maps geodesics to geodesics, without necessarily preserving the actual distance, right?

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$Let's fix a positive real number $r$ and consider the statement, *A cylinder of radius $r$ is locally isometric to the plane*. Technicalities are hidden below to make them easier to skip on first reading. (To the casual reader, SE's default tag *spoiler* therefore refers to *fun spoiler*. :)

### Physical Intuition

The basic physical picture is a flat sheet of paper (a model of a piece of a Euclidean plane) rolled into a tube (a model of a circular cylinder). Intuitively, this mapping is a local isometry because while the paper bends in space, it does not stretch, wrinkle, or tear. By contrast, if we attempt to wrap a flat sheet of paper around a tennis ball (of "positive Gaussian curvature") or a concave vase (of "negative Gaussian curvature"), the paper will wrinkle or tear.

Note 1:

> If we're more careful, physical paper is a thin slab of inhomogeneous medium (cellulose fibers) that *does* slightly stretch and compress when rolled into a tube: That's why we have to tape the tube closed to prevent it from unrolling if we let go. By "no stretching" in the preceding paragraph we mean something like "no first-order stretching in directions tangent to the flat surface of the paper."

In this physical model, arcs of plane geodesics are arbitrary line segments. Under rolling up, these map to curves on the cylinder that turn out to be circular helices, including degenerate cases of "equatorial" circles and Euclidean "meridian" lines.

The Euclidean distance between points of the plane is not generally preserved under rolling paper into a tube; for example, two points at distance $2\pi r$ may land at the same location on the cylinder. What *is* true, however, is that if $D$ is a Euclidean disk of radius at most $\pi r/2$, then Euclidean distances in $D$ agree with cylindrical distances in the image of $D$ under wrapping. That's a concrete way to understand *local isometry*.

### Analytic Model

For convenience, introduce Cartesian coordinates $(u, v)$ in the Euclidean plane. To a differential geometer, Euclidean geometry is captured by the *first fundamental form*
$$
g = du^{2} + dv^{2},
$$
an infinitesimal articulation of the Pythagorean theorem that is "the same at every point."

Consider the mapping
$$
(x, y, z) = f(u, v) = (r\cos(u/r), r\sin(u/r), v).
$$
A short calculation shows the Euclidean *space* metric $dx^{2} + dy^{2} + dz^{2}$ on the image cylinder corresponds to the Euclidean *plane* metric $du^{2} + dv^{2}$. In this sense, we can "wrap" the plane isometrically around the cylinder by a mapping, and we can "unwrap" the plane isometrically from the cylinder, though not by a mapping.

Note 2 (local isometry):

> The image of $f$ is the cylinder with Cartesian equation $x^{2} + y^{2} = r^{2}$. The *induced metric* on the Euclidean plane is the *pullback* $f^{*}(dx^{2} + dy^{2} + dz^{2})$ of the Euclidean three-space metric, i.e., the result of "expressing $dx^{2} + dy^{2} + dz^{2}$ as a function of $u$, $v$, $du$, and $dv$." Since $dx = -\sin(u/r)\, du$, $dy = \cos(u/r)\, du$, and $dz = dv$, we have $f^{*}(dx^{2} + dy^{2} + dz^{2}) = du^{2} + dv^{2}$, the Euclidean plane metric.

One precise claim that "There is no unwrapping from the cylinder to the plane" is: There exists no continuous mapping $\phi$ from the cylinder to the plane satisfying $f(\phi(x, y, z)) = (x, y, z)$ for all points of the cylinder.

This is a little striking because we *can* unwrap small pieces of the cylinder, and even some "large" pieces of the cylinder. (Precisely, if $D$ is a subset of the plane on which $f$ is injective--does not send two distinct points to the same location--then the image $f(D)$ is unwrapped to $D$ by "undoing" $f$.)

Intuitively, each point of the cylinder comes from infinitely many "avatars" in the plane; for example, $p = (r, 0, 0)$ in the cylinder is $f(2\pi rk, 0)$ for every integer $k$, so the single point $p$ has avatars $(u, v) = (2\pi rk, 0)$ in the plane. If we try to define $\phi(r, 0, 0) = (r, 0)$ and "extend by continuity," we run into trouble when we traverse the circle $z = 0$: While the point on the cylinder returns to its initial location, its avatar (image under $\phi$) moves to a neighboring avatar.

Note 3 (no mapping from the cylinder to the plane):

> We *can* define an "unwrapping" from the cylinder to the plane, for example by restricting $f$ to the set of $(u, v)$ with $-\pi r< u \leq \pi r$, but this mapping is not continuous along the line $x = -r$, $y = 0$. For instance, the half-open plane segment $-\pi r < u \leq \pi r$ and $v = 0$ maps bijectively to the circle $z = 0$ on the cylinder, but points "near" $(-r, 0, 0) = f(\pi r, 0)$ with $y < 0$ come from points near $(-\pi r, 0)$, while $(-r, 0, 0)$ itself comes from $(\pi r, 0)$. A careful proof that no continuous unwrapping exists might start by defining $\phi(r, 0, 0) = (0, 0)$, assuming $\phi$ is continuous, and showing that of necessity we have $\phi(r\cos(u/r), r\sin(u/r), 0) = (u, 0)$ for $0 \leq u < 2\pi$. We are forced to a discontinuity of $\phi$ at $(r, 0, 0)$.

### Local Isometries and Geodesics

Note 4:

> [Geodesics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) are solutions of a [second-order ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Affine_geodesics) whose coefficients are [Christoffel symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols). Since Christoffel symbols are determined "intrinsically" by the metric of a surface despite their apparent [dependence on bending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Codazzi_equations#Statement_of_classical_equations), geodesics map to geodesics under local isometry. In my version of Ted Shifrin's Open Math Notes at this writing (Version 2), the details of this story are in Section 2.3, starting on page 57. The version with *moving frames* is in Section 3.3, starting on page 101.

Comment: This answer goes above and beyond what is required in coverage and clarity. Thanks for taking the time to  write it.